# Output of CIFilter has different effect for different sizes of same image

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession, cifilter, avcapture, avcapturevideodataoutput

```
func getImageWithFilter(by filterType: MainViewModel.FilterType,
    image: CIImage) -> CIImage {

    guard filterType.filterEnabled,
        let filter = CIFilter(name: filterType.rawValue)
    else {
        return image
    }
    filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    return filter.outputImage ?? image
}
```

[image]
[image]

I have two output:

- AVCaptureVideoDataOutput for preview
- AVCapturePhotoOutput for save photo in hightResolution.

After applied filters i get different results

Help me please resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because most parameters of built-in Core Image filters operate on a pixel basis. In your case it's the `inputRadius` parameter of the `CICrystallize` filter. From the docs:

> The radius determines how many pixels are used to create the effect. The larger the radius, the larger the resulting crystals.

That means that you need to set the parameter to different values depending on the input size.

I usually calculate some kind of factor that I multiply with my base parameter value. For instance:

```
let inputSizeFactor = min(inputImage.size.width, inputImage.size.height) / 1000
let scaledRadius = radius * inputSizeFactor
filter.setValue(scaledRadius, forKey: "inputRadius")
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work perfect for CICrystallize. Can you say me parameters for CIGaussianBlur and CIComicEffect?

Comment: No problem. You can easily find them on https://cifilter.io. For `CIGaussianBlur` it's also `inputRadius`, but `CIComicEffect` actually doesn't have any parameters. So I guess your only choice there would be to scale the image to a desired size before applying the effect and scale it back again afterwords (loosing some quality in the process).

Answer (score 0):

As @FrankRupprecht mentioned,

> This happens because most parameters of built-in Core Image filters
> operate on a pixel basis. In your case it's the inputRadius parameter
> of the CICrystallize filter.

To get the same output, I usually apply an intuitive approach.

1. First Step:

> Apply `CIAffineClamp` filter, which takes your image in infinite extent. See [cifilter.io/CIAffineClamp/](https://cifilter.io/CIAffineClamp/)

2. Second Step:

> Apply any filter like `CICrystallize, CIComicEffect, CIGaussianBlur...`

3. Final Step:

> Crop the image according to source image extends

```
let outputImage = sourceImage // Step 1
        .applyingFilter("CIAffineClamp", parameters: [
            "inputTransform": CGAffineTransform.identity
        ])
        .applyingFilter("CIGaussianBlur") // Step 2

guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage,
      let cgImage = contex.createCGImage(outputImage, from: sourceImage.extent) // Final Step
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```